# Erro cypress integration feature ParseError Unexpected token

Tags: bdd, cypress

Quando eu clico no Cypress para executar um teste simples ele gera erro. Por favor veja o exemplo abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas steps de teste estão todas elas retornando **true**, não era para gerar erro como você podem ver no arquivo abaixo;

```
import { Given } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import { When } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import { Then } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";

Given(/^eu acesso o sistema$/, () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.facebook.com/')
});


When(/^clico no menu de acesso$/, () => {
    return true;
});

When(/^preencho o formulário$/, () => {
    return true;
});

When(/^finalio o formulário$/, () => {
    return true;
});

Then(/^verifico a mensagem de sucesso$/, () => {
    return true;
});
```

Estou achando que o problema é de configurações do projeto, vou deixar meu arquivo do GitHub para vocês verem como estar configurado. Toda ajuda e bem vinda, estarei esperando um retorno.

https://github.com/wladyband/testCypress

OBS: **Se trata de um projeto Cypress com a tentativa que implementar o BDD**

Esse é o arquivo Feature.

```
Feature: frontEnd

    Como usuario, desejo utilizar o sistema dese
    Wladimir

Scenario: Realizar lancamentos no sistema
    Given eu acesso o sistema
    And clico no menu de acesso
    When preencho o formulário
    And finalio o formulário
    Then verifico a mensagem de sucesso
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara, isso é um problema de sintaxe javascript, não consegui ver seu código pois seu repositório é privado.
Seu erro é `Unexpected Token` e qual é o token inesperado? `Como usuario, dejeso utilizar o sistema dese` que é bem parecido com o texto que você colocou.
Outro problema é que o arquivo é `.feature` e não sei se o cypress utiliza esse tipo de arquivo, meus testes estão sempre `.spec.js`

O mais provável é que você esqueceu de colocar o texto como comentário ao salvar o arquivo, um // em cada linha pode resolver, ou um atalho como SHIFT + ALT + A no Visual Studio Code.

Aqui um exemplo de como eu faço meus testes: https://github.com/vitorgamer58/AluraPic/blob/master/cypress/integration/app.spec.js